# Locking HashSet for concurrency

Tags: c#, .net

When using a `HashSet<string>` to check, whether an item was handled before (i.e. only `Add` and `Contains` is used). Furthermore it is not relevant, when Contains returns false, even though it was added before ...

I encountered following exception without locking:

> [IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
>   System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value) +6108128

Is it sufficient, to lock only the Add call?

Following seems to work forever - but that is not a proof...

```
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(GetString(), h => 
{
    hashSet.Contains(h);
    lock(hashSetLock) 
    {
        hashSet.Add(h); 
    }
    hashSet.Contains(h);
});
```

To make it precise: I know that it is not thread-safe to call `Contains` without a lock. My question is (accepting false positives) if the above code could throw an exception or could destroy the internal state of the underlying data structure (=HashSet).

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It was just a test to reproduce it ...

Comment: This isn't a very good example. There are a lot of ways to produce this hashset in a thread-safe way. If you really want to modify the collection from  multiple threads, you can use a ConcurrentDictionary<string,string> that uses the same values as key and value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient to lock only on `Add`.

The fact that it doesn't crash only tells you that it didn't crash during your test.

You cannot guarantee that:

- It won't crash in the future
- It will produce the correct results

A non-threadsafe data structure has no guarantees whatsoever if used in a multithreaded fashion.

You need to either:

- Lock on every call to it
- Use a threadsafe data structure, one that has been built to support this scenario

If you use a different data structure than a hashset, like a dictionary, you may even need to lock multi-statements, because this may still fail:

```
lock (dLock)
    if (d.ContainsKey("test"))
        return;

var value = ExpensiveCallToObtainValue();
lock (dLock)
    d.Add("test", value);
```

Between the call to `ContainsKey` and the call to `Add` another thread may have already inserted that key.

To handle this correctly, without using a threadsafe data structure, is contain both operations inside the same lock:

```
lock (dLock)
{
    if (!d.ContainsKey("test"))
        d.Add("test", ExpensiveCallToObtainValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew, that my test is not a guarantee / proof (as I already stated in the question :)). To narrow it down, my question is, whether Contains could throw an exception ... (false positives are not a problem for me as well...)

Comment: The answer is that you have no guarantee that it won't.

Comment: Please add the code to do it correctly, it's easy to take the wrong code snippet you provided for the correct way of doing it.

Comment: In my case no Remove on HashSet is being made, but Add is being used. I made some heavy tests and did not catch a single exception on the Contains call. Also I examined the Contains code from Reflector and I could not find something that would cause an Exception if no Remove is being made. However I didn't feel comfortable when I read this answer and surround Contains with a try catch that uses goto. Yes the code looked ugly but my measurements show that it is faster than using a lock, because no exception ever occured.

Comment: I can't say that it **will** crash, but the class in question isn't thread safe. The exact behavior isn't documented precisely because it isn't thread safe. For all I know it will burn down your house or chase away your dog.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen I do agree with that. I just wanted to mention that using a try-catch for Contains performed better than using a lock.

Comment: Yes, but in the case where you do get an exception you have effectively killed that execution branch, it didn't successfully execute contains so no matter what the result would be you no longer try to add something. The net result is that the code behaves differently.

Comment: if you do only Add operations, Contains is bening which means if it returns true it will remain true, if it returns false, you already double check after you take lock and it wont cause any hazards. it wont return positive values if it doesnt contain  the value. no need to be prejudiced here.

Answer (score 3):

No, as others stated, it isn't thread-safe to do what you're doing. If the underlying collection isn't thread-safe, you will need to lock on every operation.

When using a `HashSet<T>`, there need not be a `ContainsKey` check, as [`Add` will check if the internal collection already contains the value or not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value Type: System.Boolean
>
> true if the element is added to the
>   HashSet object; false if the element is already present.

So you can narrow your code to:

```
private readonly object syncRoot = new object();
lock (syncRoot)
    hashSet.Add(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of those calls to `Contains()`? They don't do anything. If you want to add only if the set does not contain an item, then you can do the following:

```
if(!hasSet.Contains(h))
{
   lock(hashSetLock)
   {
      if(!hasSet.Contains(h))
      {
         hashSet.Add(h);
      }
   }
}
```

With this code you don't lock to check the existing of the element, but if the element was not set you have to check again after locking. What do you gain? You don't lock in case the element already exists.

Comment: `HashSet<T>.Contains` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, so you cannot really call it without the lock.

Comment: doing the lock is expensive, Add already does the contains, so no need to do it in the lock, but by doing it ounce outside the lock, you can avoid the expensive lock if the value already is in the hashset.
Unless someone can explain in what way a contains could fail (as in throw or cause corruption) if not locked, than it is a good compromise for code which needs high performance (at least sometimes)