# Dictionary return object having count -1 ArithmeticFlowException

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset, arithmetic-overflow

I am facing an issue in Arithmetic overflow, I have posted the detail in this question [[Dictionary to ToList ArithmeticFlowException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736578/dictonary-to-tolist-arithmeticflowexception][1])

however I have found the reason, when I call the method

```
Global.SereverConnections.TryGetValue(key, out connections);
```

it throws overflow exception, having count of connections is equal to -1.

```
public static  IDictionary<string, ISet<ConnectionManager>> SereverConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ISet<ConnectionManager>>();

public static IList<ConnectionManager> GetUserConnections(string username)
{
    //Key must not be null in any case return null if someone send and empty username
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        return null;
    ISet<ConnectionManager> connections;

    Global.SereverConnections.TryGetValue(username, out connections);
    //this will make the copy of the 
    //return (connections != null ? connections.ToList() ?? Enumerable.Empty<ConnectionManager>().ToList() : null);

     //exception occurs in below line, and connections.Count==-1
    return (connections != null ? connections.ToList() : null); 
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that suggests how this happens. Wild guess: `Global.SereverConnections` is accessed from multiple threads, causing the dictionary to end up with an inconsistent state.

Comment: Can you share when the count of object is equal to -1 in dictionary. what is the behavior ?

Comment: Yes am using this in multithreaded environment, am doing load test @JeroenMostert

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have declared it ConcurrentDictionary, still I need locking mechanism for it?

Comment: No, because `ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue` is thread-safe. But `connections.ToList` is not. (Nor is enumeration ever a thread-safe operation, no matter what collection you use -- there is no `.ToList()` that will let you avoid locking.)

Answer (score 1):

`Global.SereverConnections` is a `ConcurrentDictionary`, and thus is [thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety). But you are adding `HashSet`s to it - and they are not [thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx#Thread%20Safety).

You can't call `HashSet.ToList()` at the same time as [someone is adding items to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096775/locking-hashset-for-concurrency).

*You will need to use locking around all accesses to the `HashSet` to ensure that you don't have threading issues. Or switch to using `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of `HashSet` (as per [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922985/concurrent-hashsett-in-net-framework).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922985/concurrent-hashsett-in-net-framework)._)*

Comment: will it solve the problem if I replace hashset with the the ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Yes have change the hasset to concurrent dictonary